# FFMPEG overlay video with black background over an image not working without any errors

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a snow effect video with black background snow.mp4, and i want to overlay it over a fixed jpeg image.jpg
The generated output video result was only with the image without the snow effect, my ffmpeg version is: 3.2.10, i don't understand why it is not working with me, have you an idea?

This is my command line:

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -i snow.mp4 -filter_complex '[1:v]scale=1280x768,setdar=16:9,colorkey=0x000000:0.3:0.2[ckout];[0:v]scale=1280x768,setdar=16:9,[ckout]overlay[out]' -map '[out]' output.mp4
```

I tried also with the chromakey instead of colorkey, without success :/

This is the result video that i got: 
[output.mp4](https://streamable.com/s/mrkou/ondgaq)

What i want is this result with snow effect: [output_with_snow_effect.mp4](https://streamable.com/s/vgbic/qohwna)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your unlabelled pad, I believe the snow is used as the overlay bg.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -i snow.mp4 -filter_complex '[1:v]scale=1280x768,setdar=16:9,colorkey=0x000000:0.3:0.2[ckout];[0:v]scale=1280x768,setdar=16:9[bg];[bg][ckout]overlay[out]' -map '[out]' output.mp4
```

Comment: Great! yes if forget it, it works fine now, thank you ;)